# Simplify Mod to subtraction when possible

Tags: simplifying-expressions, modular-arithmetic

`FullSimplify[Mod[t,10], t>101 && t<109]`

It's a long shot, but can I get Mathematica to return `t-100` or something similar for the above?

Currently it returns just `Mod[t,10]` itself, which is accurate, but I want even more simplification based on my conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
Assuming[101 < t < 109, FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[Mod[t, 10]]]]
```

---

rhermans gives a simpler formulation:

```
PiecewiseExpand[Mod[t, 10], 101 < t < 109]
```

Comment: That works, even without the FullSimplify, but I'm not sure why, since `PiecewiseExpand[Mod[t, 10]]` just returns `Mod[t, 10]`. I'm guessing `Assuming` does some sort of `Hold` on its second argument, hmmm. Will investigate further on my own :)

Comment: That too `PiecewiseExpand[Mod[t, 10], 101 < t < 109]`

Comment: Who knew that Mod was secretly a "nested piecewise function"!

Comment: Documentation says: *"PiecewiseExpand converts such functions as `If`, `Which`, `Abs`, `Max`, `UnitStep`, and `Floor` to `Piecewise`. "*

Comment: I'm confused about the different ways the assumptions are used in each case, see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96596/10397)