# External and internal Assumptions on `PiecewiseExpand` and `Mod`

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, piecewise

After [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96594/10397) I'm intrigued about the different behaviors depending where and how the assumptions are given.

```
PiecewiseExpand[Mod[n, m]]    (* case #1 *)
(* Mod[n, m] *)

PiecewiseExpand[Mod[n, m], n == m, Integers]    (* case #2 *)
(* -m + n *)

Assuming[n == m,    (* case #3 *)
 FullSimplify@PiecewiseExpand[Mod[n, m]] 
 ]
(* 0 *)

Assuming[n == m,    (* case #4 *)
 Simplify@PiecewiseExpand[Mod[n, m]]
 ]
(* Mod[0, n] *)

Assuming[n == m,    (* case #6 *)
 FullSimplify@Mod[n, m]
 ]
(* 0 *)

Assuming[n == m,    (* case #7 *)
 Simplify@Mod[n, m]
 ]
(* Mod[0, n] *)
```

Case #5 removed as it was an unrelated bug discussed in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96599/10397)

**How is that explained?**

Comment: Items 3 and 4 exhibit the same behavior without `PiecewiseExpand[]`; item 5 is manifestly a bug.

Comment: `$Assumptions = m > 0 && Element[{n, m}, Integers]; PiecewiseExpand[Mod[n, m]]` returns `Mod[n, m]`

Comment: @rhermans I suggest copying case 5 to a new question and tagging it with _bugs_ instead of tagging THIS question :). Although we aren't a bugs repository it's nice to have a highlights catalog.