# Bug in PiecewiseExpand and Mod with assumptions

Tags: bugs, piecewise, modular-arithmetic

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.4**

---

The following code using [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html)and [`Mod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod.html)gives the wrong answer

```
PiecewiseExpand[Mod[n, m], m > 0, Integers]
```

> 0

tested in *Mathematica* v 10.2.0 Windows 7 64 and partially discussed on early version of  [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96596/10397).

*Wolfram Technical Support* case identification : **[CASE:3442254]**

Can anybody reproduce this problem in other systems?

Comment: V9.0.1 on Win32 shows the same result

Comment: V10.0.2, Mac OS X 10.10.5 shows the same problem.

Comment: Problem is repeatable on Mac OS X 10.11 with Mathematica version 10.2

Comment: With v 10.2, `$Assumptions = m > 0 && Element[{n, m}, Integers]; PiecewiseExpand[Mod[n, m]]` returns `Mod[n, m]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the header, this bug has been fixed as of Mathematica 10.4.0:

```
$Version                                                                

(* 10.4.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 26, 2016) *)

PiecewiseExpand[Mod[n, m], m > 0, Integers]                             

(* Mod[n, m] *)
```