# Simplify of `Mod` in compound logical expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, modular-arithmetic

It's great that

```
Simplify[Mod[x,2π]==0,Assumptions->{0<=x<2π}]
```

yields `x==0`.  However even a slightly more complicated expression,

```
expr0=Mod[x,2π]==0&&y==1
Simplify[expr0,Assumptions->{0<=x<2π}]
```

doesn't work; the `Mod` is still there.  It doesn't work with `FullSimplify`, nor if I specify `FullSimplify[expr0,ComplexityFunction->(LeafCount@#+3Count[#,Mod,Infinity]&)]`.  The question [Simplify Mod to subtraction when possible](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96592/simplify-mod-to-subtraction-when-possible) doesn't help; `PiecewiseExpand` does nothing when it's compound.

I can make custom rules for replacing `Mod` with its simplified form, but why is `Simplify` only working in small cases?

The expression I want it to work on is

```
expr1=((Mod[-π + θ, 2 π] == π && px == 1 && 
 py == 1) || (Mod[θ, π] != 0 && 
 py Csc[θ] <= Csc[θ] && 
 1 + (-1 + py) Cot[θ] >= px)) && (px != 1 || py != 1 || 
Mod[π/2 + θ, 
 2 π] != π) && (Mod[π/2 + θ, π] == 0 || 
px Sec[θ] > Sec[θ] || 
1 + (-1 + px) Tan[θ] < py) && (px != 0 || py != 0 || 
Mod[-π + θ, 
 2 π] != π) && (Mod[θ, π] == 0 || 
py Csc[θ] > 0 || py Cot[θ] < px) && (px != 0 || 
py != 0 || 
Mod[π/2 + θ, 
 2 π] != π) && (Mod[π/2 + θ, π] == 0 || 
px Sec[θ] > 0 || px Tan[θ] < py)
```

Comment: Idk, but this makes progress: `Assuming[0 <= \[Theta] < 2 \[Pi],
 Simplify[expr1, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Simplify}]
 ]`

Comment: `Reduce[expr0 && 0 <= x < 2 \[Pi]]` does what you want. But it gets stuck for expr1, even if LogicalExpanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce does this job better.

```
expr0 = Mod[x, 2 \[Pi]] == 0 && y == 1;
Reduce[expr0 && 0 <= x < 2 \[Pi]]

(*   y == 1 && x == 0   *)

expr1[px_, 
   py_, \[Theta]_] = ((Mod[-\[Pi] + \[Theta], 2 \[Pi]] == \[Pi] && 
       px == 1 && py == 1) || (Mod[\[Theta], \[Pi]] != 0 && 
       py Csc[\[Theta]] <= Csc[\[Theta]] && 
       1 + (-1 + py) Cot[\[Theta]] >= px)) && (px != 1 || py != 1 || 
     Mod[\[Pi]/2 + \[Theta], 
       2 \[Pi]] != \[Pi]) && (Mod[\[Pi]/2 + \[Theta], \[Pi]] == 0 || 
     px Sec[\[Theta]] > Sec[\[Theta]] || 
     1 + (-1 + px) Tan[\[Theta]] < py) && (px != 0 || py != 0 || 
     Mod[-\[Pi] + \[Theta], 
       2 \[Pi]] != \[Pi]) && (Mod[\[Theta], \[Pi]] == 0 || 
     py Csc[\[Theta]] > 0 || py Cot[\[Theta]] < px) && (px != 0 || 
     py != 0 || 
     Mod[\[Pi]/2 + \[Theta], 
       2 \[Pi]] != \[Pi]) && (Mod[\[Pi]/2 + \[Theta], \[Pi]] == 0 || 
     px Sec[\[Theta]] > 0 || px Tan[\[Theta]] < py);

RegionPlot3D[
 expr1[px, py, \[Theta]], {px, -5, 5}, {py, -5, 5}, {\[Theta], 0, 
  2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

```
pxmax = NMaximize[{px, 
   expr1[px, py, \[Theta]] && 0 <= \[Theta] < 2 Pi}, {px, 
   py, \[Theta]}]

(*   {1., {px -> 1., py -> 1., \[Theta] -> 1.08768*10^-15}}   *)

pymax = NMaximize[{py, 
   expr1[px, py, \[Theta]] && 0 <= \[Theta] < 2 Pi}, {px, 
   py, \[Theta]}]

(*   {1., {px -> 1., py -> 1., \[Theta] -> 1.08768*10^-15}}   *)
```

For Theatamax NMinimize only gives right result with px <= 0. Also expr1 simplifies easily for that px range. Aborted red2, simplification for 0 < px< =1 due to my timelimit. Please try further.

```
\[Theta]nmax = 
 NMaximize[{\[Theta], 
    expr1[px, py, \[Theta]] && 
     0 <= \[Theta] < 2 Pi && -5 <= px <= 0}, {px, py, \[Theta]}] // 
  Quiet

(*   {3.14159, {px -> -4.99999, py -> 0.266354, \[Theta] -> 3.14159}}   *)

red1 = Reduce[
   expr1[px, py, \[Theta]] && 
    0 <= \[Theta] < 2 Pi && -5 <= px <= 0 && -5 <= py <= 1, {px, 
    py, \[Theta]}, Reals] // FullSimplify

(*   5 + px >= 0 && 
  ((px <= 0 && ((2*\[Theta] < Pi && ((py == 1 && \[Theta] > 0) || 
       (py > 0 && \[Theta] > 2*ArcTan[
           Sqrt[1 + (-1 + px)^2/(-1 + py)^2] + 
            (1 - px)/(-1 + py)] && py < 1))) || 
     (\[Theta] > 2*ArcTan[Sqrt[1 + px^2/py^2] - px/py] && 
      py > 0 && \[Theta] < Pi && py <= 1))) || 
   (py > 0 && 2*\[Theta] > Pi && px < 0 && py <= 1 && 
    \[Theta] <= 2*ArcTan[Sqrt[1 + px^2/py^2] - px/py]))   *)

red2 = Reduce[
   expr1[px, py, \[Theta]] && 0 <= \[Theta] <= Pi && 
    0 < px <= 1 && -5 <= py <= 1, {px, py, \[Theta]}, Reals] // 
  FullSimplify

(*   $Aborted   *)
```